# Submit object with ng-option

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, controller, mean-stack

I am having trouble submitting an object with [ng-option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to my controller. If I submit the form, the `Category` object is undefined.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

**ItemsController**

```
    // Create new Item
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Item object
        var item = new Items ({
            name: this.name,
            ...
            category: this.category,
        });
```

**Create Item view**

```
<section data-ng-controller="ItemsController">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>New Item</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="category">Category</label>
          <div class="controls" data-ng-controller="CategoriesController" data-ng-init="find()">
            <select data-ng-model="category" ng-options="cat.name for cat in categories"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        </div>
```

Thanks to "aurav gupta" I have found the solution http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/controllers/sharing-code-between-controllers-using-services.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are using **two different controllers**
and so they would have **different scopes.**
Hence the **category** object is defined for **CategoriesController** but not for **ItemsController**
you can solve this problem either by putting your code for CategoriesController in ItemsController so as to make a single controller or you can use angular services to bind the scope variables for two controllers.